# Ecobee restarts when calling AC - old analog thermostat worked

Tags: hvac, thermostat, central-air

I just installed an ecobee 4 and I have a C-wire so it seemed straightforward. The ecobee shows that it detected all the expected wires. However when it tries to call the AC it instantly restarts every time. The heat and the blower work, and the AC worked with the old Honeywell analog thermostat.

I read somewhere that newer equipment can be sensitive to shorts even when older equipment works fine. Could this be the case? How would I diagnose? I just moved into a condo and don't know how to access the control board yet.

[image: Old wiring]

[image: Ecobee shows all the wires detected correctly]

Comment: I see the"C" label on the old 'stat, but I am concerned it may not have the modern smart 'stat meaning of the term.  Why did the old 'stat need a C wire/constant power? Onboard computer? Backlight?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace/air handler end?

Comment: @Harper yes the ecobee has no battery so requires either a C wire or something they include called a power-extender kit. No idea what the old stat would have needed, it was an analog Honeywell with sliders, nothing digital.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just moved in to this condo, only thing I can find indoors is the stat and the circuit breaker. About to hunt for the air handler in the shared garage/backyard.

Comment: Someone on reddit commented: "Apparently the current draw is too much for the 24VAC transformer in the air handler. Consider replacing it with a new transformer that has a higher VA rating." Any thoughts on this?

Comment: My concern is that the wire labeled C on the old stat serves another purpose.  This can't be discerned without the schematic to the furnace.  If this is a multiple unit dwelling with maintenance staff, everyone probably has the same unit and staff knows it well, maybe is best left to them,

Comment: The other end of the C wire may not even be hooked up.

Comment: It's possible that the inrush current to the contactor coil is too much, and it's causing the voltage to sag.  Which is causing the Ecobee to drop out.  I would expect the Ecobee to have circuitry to guard against this, but maybe your transformer is too small (or sized too closely to the load).

Answer (score 1):

I talked to my landlord to inquire about access to the actual equipment and it turns out its on the roof and not happening. However, he said he had the same problem with his unit and his Nest and to solve it he just removed the C wire. A big difference between the Ecobee and the Nest is that Nest has a battery and therefore does not require a C wire. I got one, wired it up with the same config as posted, minus C wire, and it was able to call the AC right away. Some commenters mentioned that my C wire might not actually do what it is labeled as, but it did power on the Ecobee. So either I had a bad Ecobee or it isn't able to handle certain funky situations that the Nest can. Maybe the lack of C wire affects the current draw, but hard to say since I never accessed the equipment.